# Addition of Numbers in Multiple Moduli

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I want to do arithmetic in base 60, but since remembering 60 different symbols is difficult, I want to represent each digit by its value mod 3, 4, and 5 (equivalent by the Chinese remainder theorem). Adding the digits is as simple as adding each modulus separately. However, knowing when to carry one to the next higher power of 60 is something I haven't figured out yet.

The question is this:
If I know the remainders mod 3,4,5 of two nonnegative integers x,y < 60, is there an algorithm for determining if x+y >= 60 without computing the values of x,y?

Comment: `remembering 60 different symbols`. Think of hours, minute, seconds.

Comment: @Bernard I usually write Minutes and Seconds in decimal, so it isn't a pure base 60 system. It's like the Babylonian's base 60 system. I am hoping for something more pure base 60, so I want 60 different symbols.

Comment: Yet, remembering how to add times in hours, minutes and seconds helps!

Comment: How is it easier to denote each place value by three digits rather than two as you would if using the normal representation?

Comment: I have no idea to determine whether $x+y\ge 60$ WITHOUT calculating them, but I could given you an easy formula to convert the residues mod $3,4,5$ to the corresponding residue mod $60$

Comment: Such an algorithm would have to be quite sensitive to the input, in such a way that algorithms doing this are probably as efficient as actually computing $x$ and $y$. For example, $(1\bmod2,1\bmod3,1\bmod5)+(0\bmod2,2\bmod3,4\bmod5)$ is $31+44>60,$ but $(1\bmod2,2\bmod3,1\bmod5)+(0\bmod2,2\bmod3,4\bmod5)$ is $11+44<60.$

Comment: @Joffan It is more a matter of taste than anything. I am imagining a society that uses base 60 for its compositeness, but comes up with a different way of representing those digits as a composite symbol made of what that digit mod 3,4,5 would be.

Comment: It seems the best that can be done is to compute the value of x+y, so this question has no answer. I am not what to do about the question though.